# Getting started with opencv and openKinect (libfreenect)

Tags: c++, opencv, openkinect

Does anyone have any starting points for this? What code I can find on openkinect's site is outdated and opencv's site only talks about OpenNI, not OpenKinect

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be the openkinect.org website is outdated. But their git repos look pretty active : https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect

Comment: Noted. Thanks for that